# Button Not Changing Label Position On Click?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am creating a rogue-like game. I would like to make it sort of like the game "The Ensign" if anyone is familiar with it. When I try to make North, East, South, and West buttons, I am having trouble making the character, move. Why doesn't this button change the position of the label? Any better ways to do this?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Rogue_Like2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public int _x;
        public int _y;

        public Form1()

        {
            InitializeComponent();

            _x = lbl_char.Location.X;
            _y = lbl_char.Location.Y;
        }

        private void btn_north_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _x -= 10;
        }

        private void btn_south_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _y += 10;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `_x = lbl_char.Location.X` doesn't give you the reference of `lbl_char.Location.X` but only the current value, so your `_x -= 10;` doesn't do anything. You probably need to do something like `lbl_char.Location = new Location(lbl_char.Location.X - 10, lbl_char.Location.Y)`

Comment: Ahh, thanks so much! "lbl_char.Location = new Point(lbl_char.Location.X - 10, lbl_char.Location.Y);"  - worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to move the label, try this

```
lbl_char.Location = new Point( x, y);
```